# I want to display top 3 student by marks but instead it is displaying top 3 of stack

Tags: c++, stack

Everything is working good instead I want to get top 3 students by their marks to be displayed but I am getting top 3 students of the stack. I am a beginner. Please help
Add some students (5 or 6) and their marks.
when I click 4, it want it to display top 3 students by marks.
I think I am missing some part where I need to compare marks of the students but having some trouble.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static std::size_t sizeOfStack { 0 };

class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    int marks;
    Student* nextStudent;

    void setName( string setn )
    {
        name = setn;
    }

    string getName( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    void setMarks( int setm )
    {
        marks = setm;
    }

    int getMarks( )
    {
        return marks;
    }

    void setNextStudent( Student* setAddress )
    {
        nextStudent = setAddress;
    }

    Student* getNextStudent()
    {
        return nextStudent;
    }
};

class Stack
{
public:
    Student* headStudent { NULL };

    bool isEmpty( )
    {
        if ( headStudent == NULL )
        {
            cout << '\n' << "Stack is Empty" << '\n';
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void push( )
    {
        string studentName;
        int marks;
        Student* newNode = new Student;
        cout << "Enter the name of Student: " << '\n';
        cin >> studentName;
        newNode->setName( studentName );
        cout << "Enter the Marks of Student: " << '\n';
        cin >> marks;
        newNode->setMarks( marks );
        newNode->setNextStudent( NULL );
        if ( headStudent == NULL )
        {
            headStudent = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Student* ptr = headStudent;
            while ( ptr->getNextStudent( ) != NULL )
            {
                ptr = ptr->getNextStudent();
            }
            ptr->setNextStudent( newNode );
        }

        cout << '\n' << "Student Data saved successfully" << '\n';
        ++sizeOfStack;
    }

    void pop( )
    {
        if ( !isEmpty( ) )
        {
            Student* pre = headStudent;
            Student* ptr = headStudent;
            while ( ptr->getNextStudent() != NULL )
            {
                pre = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->getNextStudent( );
            }
            if ( ptr == headStudent )
            {
                headStudent = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                pre->setNextStudent( NULL );
            }
            delete ptr;
            --sizeOfStack;
            cout << '\n' << "Student Data Remove Successfully from database" << '\n';
        }
    }

    void display( )
    {
        if ( !isEmpty( ) )
        {
            string studentNames[ sizeOfStack ] { };
            int studentMarks[ sizeOfStack ] { };
            int i { };
            int j { };
            cout << "*************************" << '\n';
            cout << "The Data of All students: " << '\n';
            cout << "Name\t\tMarks"<< '\n';
            Student* ptr = headStudent;
            while ( ptr != NULL )
            {
                studentNames[i++] = ptr->getName( );
                studentMarks[j++] = ptr->getMarks( );
                ptr = ptr->getNextStudent( );
            }
            for ( std::size_t idx = sizeOfStack - 1; idx >= 0; --idx )
            {
                cout<< studentNames[ idx ] << "\t\t" << studentMarks[ idx ] <<'\n';
            }
            cout << "*************************" << '\n';
        }
    }

    void shortStack( )
    {
        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfStack; ++i )
        {
            Student* ptr = headStudent;

            for ( std::size_t j = 0; j < sizeOfStack - 1; ++j )
            {
                string tmp;
                if ( ptr->getMarks( ) < ptr->getNextStudent( )->getMarks( ) )
                {
                    // ptr->setMarks(ptr->getMarks() + ptr->getNextStudent()  );
                    // some statement Goes here
                }
                ptr = ptr->getNextStudent( );
            }
        }
    }

    void top( )
    {
        if ( !isEmpty( ) )
        {
            // shortStack();
            cout << "\n\n" << "Top Positions:" << '\n';
            cout << '\n' << "Name\t\tMarks";
            Student* ptr = headStudent;

            for( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx )
            {
                cout << '\n' << ptr->getName( ) << "\t\t" << ptr->getMarks( );
                ptr = ptr->getNextStudent( );
            }

            cout << "\n\n";
        }
    }
};


int main( )
{
    Stack s;

    while ( true )
    {
        int choice { };
        cout << '\n' << "*************************************************" << '\n';
        cout << "1. To Add a student in the stack" << '\n';
        cout << "2. To Remove a student from stack" << '\n';
        cout << "3. Display all students of stack" << '\n';
        cout << "4. Display top 3 students of stack" << '\n';
        cout << "5. Press 5 or any other key to close the program" << '\n';
        cout << "*************************************************" << '\n';
        cout << "Enter your choice (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):" << '\n';
        cin >> choice;

        switch ( choice )
        {
            case 1:
                s.push( );
                break;
            case 2:
                s.pop( );
                break;
            case 3:
                s.display( );
                break;
            case 4:
                s.top( );
                break;
            default:
                exit( 0 );
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use a stack?

Comment: Do you want the 3 students with best marks to be displayed or do you want the top 3 elements of the stack to be displayed?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `shortStack`? Do you mean sort??

Comment: Yes I want 3 students with best marks to be displayed in descending order.

Comment: I am using stack because my university assignment says so.

Comment: @luziamas Which compiler are you using to compile this code? Which version?

Comment: Dev C++ @digito_evo

Comment: @luziamas Dev C++ is an IDE. But I think it uses MinGW or something similar as its compiler.

Comment: @digito_evo In the edit you did, When I type 3 to display all students in stack, it does shows all the students but the program ends there. It does not ask for options again.

Comment: @luziamas I did not fix your code. I just refactored it so that it becomes more readable. Does it behave the way you want in your own version? If so then we'll have to request the original version to be reverted back.

Answer (score 0):

First problem that i encountered within your code is in your display function:

```
for ( std::size_t idx = sizeOfStack - 1; idx >= 0; --idx )
```

- This for statement can be interpreted as "Decrement `idx` until it becomes less than 0". Unfortunately this can never be the case because of the type of your `idx` variable.
- `std::size_t` is defined for unsigned values so if you decrement it further it becomes a very large number rather than being negative, which ends up as a segmentation fault in your code.
- Following lines might be useful to overcome that issue if you really need to use `std::size_t`.

  ```
  for ( std::size_t idx = sizeOfStack; idx > 0; --idx )
  {
      cout << studentNames[ idx-1 ] << "\t\t" << studentMarks[ idx-1 ] <<'\n';
  }
  ```

Secondly, sorting the elements in your stack can help with the problem that you stated in your post. That way you will be able to print the top 3 marks easily.

Here's the sorting algorithm that i can provide for you:

```
void sortStack( )
{
    Student* ptr = headStudent;
    Student std_array[sizeOfStack];
    
    // copy the elements in the stack
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfStack; i++)
    {
        std_array[i] = *ptr;
        ptr = ptr->getNextStudent();
    }

    // sort elements of the array
    for(std::size_t j = 0; j < sizeOfStack-1; j++)
    {
        for(std::size_t k = j+1; k < sizeOfStack; k++)
        {
            if(std_array[j].getMarks() < std_array[k].getMarks())
            {
                Student tmpStd = std_array[j];
                std_array[j] = std_array[k];
                std_array[k] = tmpStd;
            }
        }
    }

    // update the stack according to the sorted values
    ptr = headStudent;
    for(std::size_t l = 0; l < sizeOfStack; l++)
    {
        ptr->setName(std_array[l].getName());
        ptr->setMarks(std_array[l].getMarks());
        ptr = ptr->getNextStudent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing virtual university assignment I think. In this task instructor told us to use only stack using link list. No need of array implementation will be considered !!!!1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).